# NiFi PutSFTP 1.2.0 - Stop Option Not Always Displayed

Tags: apache-nifi

In NiFi 1.2.0, using a two-node cluster, I have a simple flow with two processors:

1. GenerateFlowFile 1.2.0 - Generates data files
2. PutSFTP 1.2.0 - SCP puts files

Often after I've started both processors and let them run for a short while, I can stop the GenerateFlowFile processor, but I'm not able to stop (or start, for that matter) the PutSFTP processor. The *Start* and *Stop* items don't display in the context menu, and I can only view and not edit the processor's configuration. The PutSFTP processor's status icon indicates that it is stopped.

I'm not convinced that the behavior that I'm seeing is specific PutSFTP processors.

Why might this processor be "unstoppable"?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to the question, but I just noticed that, when I refresh my browser, the PutSFTP process is startable again. The problem seems to lie with the Web application failing to update the processor's context menu for some reason.

I'm using Chrome 62.0.3202.94 (64-bit).